# Android Background Service in SDK > 26 with SignalR

Tags: android, signalr, android-service

From what I understand, Background Services, are, not really supported any more within Android SDK >26 unless the app is in the foreground.

Silly question, I presume a foreground app, is an app that is actively running, loaded, and on the front of the screen, visible, and the screen not locked?

My goal is to listen to a SignalR service in order to provide notifications in real time. It appears that there are all sorts of realtime notifications, but SignalR will not be one of them. I can connect every minute or so to collect notifications, but fundamentally, this will not be real time.

Is my understanding correct so far?

So it appears that the only way I can solve this is by using Firebase Cloud Messaging and hook into that from the C# side.

Please advise if there's a way to achieve Push Notifications with SignalR by creating my own Android service that will run in the background and receive notifications even when the app is closed?

Comment: I see no errors in your analysis. Obligatory reference to: https://dontkillmyapp.com/

Comment: That's not quite true.  Background services are short lived.  They still have uses,  they just can't be around for more than a minute or two.  And really its been practically that way for most of a decade.

Comment: Just to confirm then - Firebase Cloud Messaging has to be employed here.

Comment: Additional - how do Facebook et al get real time notifications working without a foreground service? That must mean there's some kind of approval / review process for people who want to provide a service like this?